# asp:LinkButton code to open new browser window/tab after other code

Tags: c#, asp.net

For my internal webpage at work, I display a DataGrid based on entries in a SQL table (not directly, but with some processing on entries).

Each row in the DataGrid has a button that the user clicks. I need this button to open a new window or tab (I believe I can't decide as this is based on browser config) and also change a value in the SQL table to say the button was clicked.

If I use an asp:Hyperlink then the page opens nicely, but I don't know how to update SQL. Vice-versa if I use an asp:LinkButton I can get the SQL updated but can't get a new page to open.

Is what I am trying to do impossible?

Thanks

EDIT:

I've tried both these in my .cs file, but neither worked:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "openwindow", "window.open('" + url + "','_preview'");

Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>detailedresults=window.open('" + url + "');</script>");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use LinkButton and use OnClientClick property to set the java-script that would open the page in new browser window. This script must return true so that post-back can happen and you can handle click event on server side to update your database.

IMO, better way would be to use hyper-link and open the page in new browser window. However, you must pass a query-string parameter while opening the page (say Page2) that would tell the new page that it should update the database. So url for opening the page will be something like `"page2.aspx?recordId=xyz"`. And within page2.aspx.cs, you will have code such as

```
protected void page_load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (!IsPostback)
   {
      var recordId = Response.QueryString["recordId"];
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(recordId))
      {
         // update database
         ...
      }
   }
   ...
}
```

From security perspective, you may want to include time-out within parameter value and encrypt the entire thing.

Comment: Having tried several methods to use ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript/Response.Write, I failed to get them working. This might be down to incorrect usage, but in the end I went with VinayC's suggestion. Implemented a new .aspx page that gets passed a QueryString. This page then updates SQL and redirects to the URL. Works perfectly for my needs. No security issues as this is purely internal work website. Thanks!

Comment: @neildeadman, RegisterStartupScript (to register script that opens the browser page) would have worked but main issue with that approach would have been pop-up blocker - new page opened with start-up script would be treated as a advertise/pop-up and would be blocked. You might have faced the same issue while trying other's solutions.

Answer (score 2):

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action"> <ItemTemplate>
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnConfigureSurvey" runat="server" CausesValidation="False"    
CommandName="ConfigureSurvey" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("intSurveyID") %>' 
OnClientClick="aspnetForm.target ='_blank';">                                        
</asp:LinkButton>
</ItemTemplate>                               
</asp:TemplateField>

protected void gvSurveyList_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
 if (e.CommandName == "ConfigureSurvey")
{
  Response.Redirect('Your page url');
}
}
```

Comment: Hey Raghubir, welcome:) It's always good to start with some explanation and then follow that with code. It would be great if you can add some commentary to your answer that would help any future readers.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>detailedresults=window.open('PAGE NAME.aspx');</script>")
```

**EDIT:**

you can set command name for link button and execute code in rowcocommand event

```
 protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName.Equals("commandname for linkbutton"))
            {
                //update code 
                Response.Write("<SCRIPT language=\"javascript\">open('Yourpage.aspx','_blank','top=0,left=0,status=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes');</script>");

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use your LinkButton and call [RegisterStartupScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/asz8zsxy%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) on postback to execute something like this on page load

.aspx:

```
<asp:LinkButton OnClick="OnButtonClick" Text="Update" runat="server" />
```

.aspx.cs:

```
protected void OnButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "openwindow", "<script type=text/javascript> window.open('About.aspx'); </script>");
}
```

You need to supply the whole script element to RegisterStartupScript.

Answer (score 0):

Hyperlink will not call server side event on click, so you won't get post back to perform the SQL task, and by using the LinkButton you can open the page in the new window or tab. To do so you need to add a little code below in the Grid_RowBoundEvent.

Ex: LinkButton.OnClientClick="window.open('http://www.google.com');";

The url you can change as per your requirement.

Again, in the Code behind you will get a server side event. There you can do your sql task.

Hope it will be helpful to you.